# How to make a Docker image of a WordPress site?

Tags: docker

I have a WordPress site hosted by a provider on shared LAMP hosting. I want to create the Docker image of that web application so that can easily deploy the same image app anywhere and distribute among my developers. Can some one please provide the brief steps?

I am totally new to Docker.

Comment: This is a bit too broad imo. The documentation would seem a good place to start, perhaps looking specifically at the `docker build` command?

Comment: This is far too broad. From the official on-hold reasons: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch to docker isn't done in one day. First you need to become familiar with the docker tools and speech. Then you need find your own structure to handle the containers (I prefer bash scripts). Last but not least you need to build images and container for your app.
I need about three months to port my app, but after all imo it was all worth.

Here are my steps to start:

1. Normally one docker container means one running process. So at first you should think about how many containers you will finally need. I need usually 3 container for a normal java webapp (Apache HTTP,Apache Tomcat, Database)
2. Looking for existing images (for instance at docker hub) that bring all the features you need.
3. Become familiar with the images and build, start and stop containers.
4. Build your own images with your application code based on the images of step 2.
5. Bring your app locally.
6. Release your images and container to your webserver.

Comment: lets say I have a VPS on which my wordpress site is running, can't I create the docker image from the VPS directly via root access? any guide for this?

Comment: @coure2011 no way ... docker container are no virtual machines, so you can't convert an exisiting environment to a container

Answer (score 0):

First you might have to create the container by hand, which is painful, but if its to be reused multiple times it is not wasted effort, then You can commit and push the container to a public docker hub repository, providing you have a docker hub account with `docker commit  CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]`. You can then push it which is really nice as then it is publicly available to anyone using the docker search command :)